# I'm wondering if using the same one public key does not guarantee privacy in the computation of multiple data owners

Tags: public-key, homomorphic-encryption, multiparty-computation, data-privacy

- **Participating entity**: multiple data owners, computing clouds
- **Protocol**: The multiple data owners send their data to the computing clouds, which perform the computation of the data.
- **Privacy protection**: Using a public key based homomorphic encryption scheme, the multiple data owners encrypt their data before transmission. (Note: homomorphic encryption is Not a symmetric key scheme.) They perform the encryption using the same one public key generated by the clouds and they Do not access the corresponding private key.
- **My question** is that using the same one public key does not guarantee privacy?
  In the public key system, the public key is accessible to anyone and it is assumed that the private key is not revealed. (The multiple data owners do not have access to the private key.) Therefore, I think this model guarantees security.
  However, other researchers seem to think that this model does not guarantee data security.

If you know anything about this, please respond.
I appreciate your any comments.

Comment: While you are correct that encrypting with a public key does ensure privacy against passive attackers (or the "honest-but-curious" model); it doesn't necessarily imply "data security" in the more general sense (where active attackers can modify encrypted values).  Is it possible that these "other researchers" are considering this broader perspective?

Comment: @poncho Thank you for your comment. I agree with you. Fortunately, I am considering passive attackers in my scenario.